# R Convert loop into function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, apply

I would like to clean up my code a bit and start to use more functions for my everyday computations (where I would normally use for loops). I have an example of a for loop that I would like to make into a function. The problem I am having is in how to step through the constraint vectors without a loop. Here's what I mean;

```
## represents spectral data
set.seed(11)
df <- data.frame(Sample = 1:100, replicate(1000, sample(0:1000, 100, rep = TRUE)))

## feature ranges by column number
frm <- c(438,563,953,963)
to <- c(548,803,1000,993)
nm <- c("WL890", "WL1080", "WL1400", "WL1375")

WL.ps <- list()

for (i in 1:length(frm)){
  
  ## finds the minimum value within the range constraints and returns the corresponding column name  
  WL <- colnames(df[frm[i]:to[i]])[apply(df[frm[i]:to[i]],1,which.min)]
  
  WL.ps[[i]] <- WL
}

new.df <- data.frame(WL.ps)
colnames(new.df) <- nm
```

The part where I iterate through the 'frm' and 'to' vector values is what I'm having trouble with. How does one go from frm[1] to frm[2].. so-on in a function (apply or otherwise)?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function which returns column name of minimum value in each row for a particular range of columns. I have used `max.col` instead of `apply(df, 1, which.min)` to get minimum value in a row since `max.col` would be efficient compared to `apply`.

```
apply_fun <- function(data, x, y) {
   cols <- x:y
   names(data[cols])[max.col(-data[cols])]
}
```

Apply this function using `Map` :

```
WL.ps <- Map(apply_fun, frm, to, MoreArgs = list(data = df))
```